# If lyr.visible = True

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers, syntaxerror

In this very simple code, my program keeps failing at line 4, `if lyr.visible = True:`, yet if I use `Print lyr.visible` instead, I receive the response "True" or "False" for each layer in the file.  So why is my If statement not working?  The error message is not helpful to me,

> Parsing error SyntaxError:  invalid syntax (line 4).

Here is the code (using 8 spaces for a tab).

```py
mxd_doc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd_doc):
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd_doc,"",df):
                if lyr.visible=True:
                        lyr.visible=False
```

Comment: You need to be using == not = when testing a value.

Comment: You should use `==` to evaluate equality. `if lyr.visible == True:`. A single `=` is for assignment, as you have used in the following line.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. You'll probably be better off researching syntax errors in the main [so] site. Note that the most important thing new Python coders can do is to follow the tenets of [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) which asserts that you can use any indent scheme you want, as long as you want to use 4 spaces. 8 is far too many for legible code. Also, if you want to test for the truth of a Boolean variable, use the variable itself (`if lyr.visible:`), not an unnecessary comparison to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find that using `==` instead of `=` worked in my if statement as written.  My if statement was flawed.  Looking at everything I could find on the web, I would never have thought to simply use "`if lyr.visible`" -- that worked like a charm!

Comment: The change to an equivalence operator should have worked.